# Launcher List Indicator on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, kde, indicator

Is possible to install [Launcher List Indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/launcher-list-indicator-update-ppa-workspaces) on Kubuntu 16.04? Or is there something similar for Kubuntu?

Or quite general question is possible to install any unity indicator like Caffeine on Kubuntu?

Comment: I wrote LLI primarily for Unity, so while installation may be possible, it wont work in KDE